# How to check if there is a new e-mail in background - ios

Tags: ios, background, notifications

how can I check if there is a new email and show an alert to user when my app is running in background? 
For pushing a notification when app is not active I have to set a "show" time to notification but an email can be received any time... I need to check emails when my app is not active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Apple Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) to send push messages when your server detects there is a new message. Your app on the phone should not do this as it will run down the battery quickly.

Comment: finally, thank you.. People who want to learn to do this can look at these links :
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12
http://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/